# How can i use php to export a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to export just the rows of a mysql table without the table information to an xml file. I read that the mysqldump command will get the job done but I cant manage to get the correct syntax. Can someone post an example code for mysqldump command? Thank you.

```
$command="mysqldump --xml ";
```

Comment: manual knows all: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: `mysqldump --xml name_of_database` at minimum. It won't dump everything for you unless you explicitly pass in the `--all-databases option.

Answer (score 1):

Try the script on this page: http://www.chriswashington.net/tutorials/export-mysql-database-table-data-to-xml-file

Answer (score 0):

By any chance you are not trying to run that command inside `mysql_query` are you ? It wont work that way. `mysqldump` is a command line utility.

To run it from php you would need to use the `system()` function, documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

If you are on a shared host with PHP in safe mode, or the `system` function is explicitly disabled in php.ini, then you will not be able to do this.

In that case you would need to read the data from your table using a `SELECT` query and iterating on all rows and potting it into an XML file, using `XMLWriter` or `DOMDocument`

Comment: i am not sure what system() function is but i m going to check it out